# how to extract type from class property (runtime type annotation check)?

Tags: python, class

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class A(NamedTuple):
    a: str
    b: int
    c = 0.432
```

How can I check whether `a` is a string?

I have already tried:

```
>> type(A.a)
property
```

Comment: `A.a` has type `property`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

namedtuple classes created with `typing.NamedTuple` have a `_field_types` attribute that stores a dict mapping field names to type annotations:

```
A._field_types['a']
```

Remember, this will give you *annotations*, which are quite likely to be things like `'str'` (a string) or `List[int]` or other things incompatible with `isinstance` checks. Actually doing anything useful with the annotation may be harder than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of the class.

```
>>> type(A("foo", 3).a)
<class 'str'>
```

The `str` annotation is a type *hint* with no runtime meaning

```
>>> type(A(1,2).a)
<class 'int'>
```

so there is no sense in which `A.a` has a type of `str`; it's a property with a setter that will accept *any* value.

To get the type annotation at runtime:

```
>>> A.__annotations__['a']
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: yeah, but this will require instantiation of `A`. And also `type(A(5, 3).a) is int` which is wrong (from annotation perspective)

Comment: It's absolutely correct, because Python doesn't *have* runtime type-checking. The annotation is for static code analysis alone.

Comment: question was specifically about this annotations/hints and whether I can extract them at runtime.

Comment: "doesn't have runtime type-checking". Oh, this is sad

Comment: Python is unapologetically a dynamically-typed language. If you want static typing, use another language.